# how to remove radwindow confirm title bar and icon

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I am looking for a pure radwindow confirm dialog which only keeps Content and YesNoButton. I didn't find any properties to switch those off. How can I do this? I tried this :

```
public void ShowConfirm()
    {
        RadWindow.Confirm(new DialogParameters()
        {
            Header = "",

            Content = new TextBlock()
            {
                MaxWidth = 200,
                Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),
                Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
                TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap,
                Text = "Test",
                FontSize = 24
            },

            Closed = OnClosed,

            WindowStyle = this.Resources["ConfirmDialog"] as Style
        });
    }
    private void OnClosed(object sender, WindowClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        var result = e.DialogResult;
        if (result == true)
        {
            //
        }
    }


<Style x:Key="checkWeekDialog" TargetType="telerik:RadWindow">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="400"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="300"/>
        <Setter Property="Icon" Value=""/>
        <!--<Setter Property="WindowStartupLocation" Value="CenterOwner"/>-->
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    </Style>
```

Comment: In my opinion the telerik forum is the best place for this question: https://www.telerik.com/forums/wpf/window

Answer (score 0):

One way to hide the titlebar of the RadConfirm component is via the VisibleTitlebar property of the RadWindowManager:

Another way is via CSS and this class:

.rwTitlebarControls {
        display: none !important;
    }